# How to recycle mysql connection while using mysql.connector in python

Tags: python, mysql, database-connection, mysql-python, connection-timeout

I am working on some flask based api.And it is hosted in python anywhere free version[1]: http://Pythonanywhere.com.
I am using mysql.connector for establishing connection between mysql database and the code.The problem is the mysql database connection will be closed after 5 minutes. Then it will show a **MYSQL connection not available** error.how to get rid of this error?

I am establishing the connection like this

```
import mysql.connector
db_config={"host":"","user":"","password":"","database":"","raise_on_warnings":True}# "connection_timeout":86400}
mydb=mysql.connector.connect(**db_config)
```

Comment: create a database connection per request in flask. Don't run long term idle connections. There isn't a significant connection cost.

Answer (score 1):

In Pythonanywhere free version there will be a limited daily quota for Mysql connection. It seems like you are not closing your connection after use.So after some number of requests your quota will be exceeded. That is why it is showing mysql connection is not available. You should close the connection after use. Then you can reuse mysql connection within allowed quota. If you want more number of connection at a time you can consider upgrading pythonanywherepackage

For more information refer the below link,

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-close.html